# How to dynamically add points to a bar/pie chart in a Vue context?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, vue.js

I would like to bootstrap a Highcharts bar chart and later add some points to it (in a Vue container). The documentation mentions [`addPoint()`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint), [`setData()`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData)  and `update()` as means to achieve that, but none of the incantations I tried worked.

The [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-setdata-pie/) for a post-updated pie chart makes it simple to use `setData()`:

```js
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie'
  },

  series: [{
    data: []
  }]
});


// the button action
$('#button').click(function() {
  chart.series[0].setData([129.2, 144.0, 176.0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<button id="button" class="autocompare">Set new data</button>
```

I tried to replicate this in a Vue context but the chart is never updated

```js
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie'
  },

  series: [{
    data: []
  }]
});


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {},
  mounted() {
    chart.series[0].setData([129.2, 144.0, 176.0]);
    chart.redraw()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that calling `Highlights.chart` queries the DOM immediately, so doing so before Vue's `mounted` callback is called will fail, since the element doesn't exist yet. That, or it gets overwritten by Vue's rendering. Instead, you'll want to call that function *after* Vue has mounted.

As a bonus, here's a little demo (that I had way too much fun with) which shows how the library can play along with Vue. It uses a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) to redraw the chart when the corresponding property is changed.

```js
function createChart() {
  return Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'pie'
    },
    series: [{
      data: []
    }]
  })
}


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    chartData: []
  },
  mounted() {
    this.chart = createChart()
    this.setData([100, 100, 100])
  },
  methods: {
    setData(data){
      this.chartData = data
    }
  },
  watch: {
    chartData(data) {
      this.chart.series[0].setData(data)
      this.chart.redraw()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="setData([129.2, 144.0, 176.0])">Show First Dataset</button>
  <button @click="setData([180, 100.0, 20.0])">Show Second Dataset</button>
  <div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use highcharts-vue, which is a wrapper on the highcharts library.
The following are the dependencies: "highcharts": "6.1.0",
"highcharts-vue": "1.0.4",
"vue": "^2.5.2"
Demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-forked-ewn4n