# Can't set tooltip and legend dynamically in Highchart with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

I've created this code in Vue.js (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49571174/how-to-dynamically-add-points-to-a-bar-pie-chart-in-a-vue-context)) in which I create a pie chart with the data from my get request, here is the code.

HTML

```
<template v-if="this.challenge_categories.length>0">                        
  <template v-if="setOccurrences()">
    <div id="pie-container" style="min-width: 200px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
  </template>
</template>
<template v-else>
    <div id="pie-container" v-bind="setData([0])" style="min-width: 200px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</template>
```

SCRIPT VUE.JS

```
var app= new Vue({
    el:'#root',
    data(){
        return{
            challenge_categories:[],
            chartData: [],
            categories:[],
            teams:[],
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.fetchCategories();
        this.chart = this.createChart()
    },
    methods:{
        fetchCategories(){
            axios.get("/getallcategories").then(function(response){
                this.challenge_categories= response.data;
            }.bind(this));
        },

        setData(data){
              this.chartData = data
         },

         setCategories(categories){
              this.categories = categories
         },

         setOccurrences(){
             //console.log(this.challenge_categories);
             var categories_occurrences=[];
             var categories_labels=[];
             for(i=0; i<this.challenge_categories.length;i++){
                 categories_occurrences[i]= this.challenge_categories[i].occurrences;
                 categories_labels[i]= this.challenge_categories[i].category_name;
             }
             //console.log(categories_occurrences);
             //console.log(categories_labels);
             this.setData(categories_occurrences);
             this.setCategories(categories_labels);
             return true;
         },

        createChart() {
              return Highcharts.chart('pie-container', {
                  chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false,
                    type: 'pie'
                  },
                  title: {
                      text: ''
                  },
                 tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                   },
                  plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            allowPointSelect: true,
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                format: '<b>{point.categories}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                                style: {
                                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },

                   xAxis:{
                    categories:[]
                   },
                series: [{
                  data: []
                }]
              })
            }   
    },
    watch: {
        chartData(data) {
          this.chart.series[0].setData(data);
          console.log(this.chart.series[0].name);
          this.chart.redraw()
        },
        categories(categories ) {
          this.chart.axes[0].setCategories(categories);
          this.chart.redraw()
        }
      }

});
```

This works and but I can't set the legend and the tooltips with the categories I added. I can see [this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2QOh.png) (don't mind the 50/50, it's just a test)
I tried update in my last function but this didn't work, any idea?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your problems occurs because of incorrect implementation of your code. First, setting chart categories doesn't affect on chart at all. By default, appropriate "category" for every slice is taken from each point `name` property, so your way of implementation won't work. You need to change the `point` values instead of categories.

The easiest way of implementing it, looks (step by step) like that:
- get your `challenge_categories` by **axios**.
- create new `series` array with new data in your `setOccurence()` function.
- take every received category object, and parse it as a new point in new series. object defined before.
- watch all changes on `series` field in your component, and when changed - update the chart with new `series` object.

I prepared simplified example which shows how it should be implemented. Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/b2yLc1m3/1/

P.S
We have our official Vue wrapper for Highcharts, which makes the process of chart implementation much easier than with using native approach. I recommend you to take a look on that. I hope it will help you a lot.
Here is the link to **npm** package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-vue

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! I changed my code and it works like charm

Comment: And what if I need to add another chart (type column) in the same html page again fetching data with axios?  Should I create another Highcharts.chart referring to another div and create another this.chart with another name?